# Completion (as a module) of the integral closure of a Cohen-Macaulay local ring whose completion is reduced

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products, cohen-macaulay, formal-completions, regular-rings

Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a Cohen-Macaulay local ring. Let $\overline R$ be the integral closure of $R$ in the [total ring of fractions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_ring_of_fractions#:%7E:text=In%20abstract%20algebra%2C%20the%20total,that%20may%20have%20zero%20divisors) of $R$.

Let $\widehat R$ be the $\mathfrak m$-adic completion of $R$, and assume it is reduced (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytically_unramified_ring), hence $\overline R$ is a module finite extension of $R$.

Now $\widehat R \otimes_R \overline R$ has a natural $R$-algebra structure.

My question is: Is $\widehat R \otimes_R \overline R$ a normal ring ?

[ Note that since $R$ is reduced, so $\overline R$ is a normal ring by https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/030C .

(Does Serre's normality criteria help in answering my question https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre%27s_criterion_for_normality ?) ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure $\widehat{R} \otimes_R \overline{R}$ is not necessarily normal because of the following consequence of a theorem of [Heitmann (1993)](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1993-1102888-9):

**Claim.** *For every dimension $d \ge 2$, there exists a local Cohen–Macaulay UFD $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ of dimension $d$ such that $\hat{R}$ is reduced but not normal.*

Note that in this case, $R$ is normal, hence $R = \overline{R}$. There may be earlier counterexamples to your question, too.

To prove the claim, let $T$ be a complete local $\mathbf{Q}$-algebra of dimension $d$ that is Cohen–Macaulay and reduced, but not normal (for example, when $d = 2$, let $T$ be the completion of the local ring of the Whitney umbrella at the origin: $\mathbf{C}[[x,y,z]]/(x^2-y^2z)$). By Theorem 8 in [[Heitmann 1993](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1993-1102888-9)], there exists a local UFD $R$ such that $\hat{R} \cong T$.

On the other hand, we have the following affirmative answer in dimension 1:

**Proposition.** *Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be an analytically unramified noetherian local ring, and denote by $\overline{R}$ the integral closure of $R$ in the total ring of fractions of $R$. Then, $\hat{R} \otimes_R \overline{R}$ is normal.*

I don't have a reference for this, so here is a proof.

*Proof.* Consider the cocartesian diagram
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
R @>>> \overline{R}\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\hat{R} @>>> \hat{R} \otimes_R \overline{R}
\end{CD}$$
where by base change, the horizontal arrows are module-finite, and the vertical arrows are faithfully flat.

To show that $\hat{R} \otimes_R \overline{R}$ is normal, it suffices to show that every localization at a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{n} \subseteq \hat{R} \otimes_R \overline{R}$ is normal. Moreover, since $\overline{R}$ is normal, by [[Matsumura 1989](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139171762), Cor. to Thm. 23.9], it suffices to show that for every such maximal ideal, the induced homomorphism
$$\varphi_{\mathfrak{n}}\colon \overline{R}_{\mathfrak{n} \cap \overline{R}} \longrightarrow (\hat{R} \otimes_R \overline{R})_{\mathfrak{n}}$$
has normal fibers. Note that $\mathfrak{n}$ contracts to the maximal ideal in $\hat{R}$ by the integrality of the bottom horizontal arrow, and hence $\mathfrak{n} \cap R = \mathfrak{m}$.

For the closed fiber, we tensor the cocartesian diagram above by $R/\mathfrak{m}$ to obtain the cocartesian diagram
$$\begin{CD}
R/\mathfrak{m} @>>> R/\mathfrak{m} \otimes_R \overline{R}\\
@V=VV @VV=V\\
\hat{R}/\mathfrak{m}\hat{R} @>>> \hat{R}/\mathfrak{m}\hat{R} \otimes_R \overline{R}
\end{CD}$$
The closed fiber of $\varphi_{\mathfrak{n}}$ is a closed fiber of the right vertical arrow, and is therefore a finite field extension of $R/\mathfrak{m}$, which is normal.

To show that the generic fiber of $\varphi_{\mathfrak{n}}$ is normal, let $\mathfrak{p} = (0) \cap R$ be the contraction of the zero ideal in $\overline{R}_{\mathfrak{n} \cap \overline{R}}$. Since $R$ is reduced, the localization $R_\mathfrak{p}$ is a field $K$, and localizing the cocartesian diagram above at $\mathfrak{p}$, we obtain the cocartesian diagram
$$\begin{CD}
K @>=>> K\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\hat{R} \otimes_R K @>=>> \hat{R} \otimes_R K
\end{CD}$$
It therefore suffices to show that $\hat{R} \otimes_R K$ is normal. By [[Matsumura 1987](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-348031-6.50021-8), p. 261], the ring $\hat{R} \otimes_R K$ is a zero-dimensional localization of $\hat{R}$. Since $\hat{R}$ is reduced, we therefore see that $\hat{R} \otimes_R K$ is regular, hence normal. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you happen to know if my question would have a positive answer in dimension $1$?

Comment: @Louis I have attempted to prove it in the one-dimensional case.

Comment: I still have to read your proof of the dimension $1$ case  but I wonder where do we crucially use dimension $1$ so that the proof works?

Comment: This fact in dimension $1$, if true, surely then looks like something that Ratliff (or his collaborators) would have noticed ... I wonder if it appears explicitly in literature ...

Comment: @Louis In higher dimensions, the same proof likely shows that the closed fibers of $\varphi_{\mathfrak{n}}$ are normal, but I don't know how to say anything about non-closed fibers. Even for the generic fiber, one can have $\dim(\hat{R} \otimes_R K) \ge 1$, in which case the hypothesis that $\hat{R}$ is reduced doesn't imply normality. It would be nice to have a reference for the one-dimensional case!

Comment: If $R$ has dimension $1$ and is analytically unramified, then is the completion map $R \to \widehat R$ normal in the sense of Huneke, Swanson http://services.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/algebra/integral-closure-ideals-rings-and-modules?site_view=desktop, Definition 19.0.1. ? If so, then we are done by Theorem 19.4.2.

Comment: The Definition of a normal homomorphism as in Huneke Swanson is: $f: R \to S $ is called normal, if it is flat and all the fibers are Geometrically normal i.e. for every prime ideal $P$ of $R$, if L is a field extension of $Frac(R/P)$, then $S \otimes_R L $ is normal

Comment: @Louis Unfortunately, this is not always the case: Nagata constructed a DVR $R$ such that the generic fiber of $R \to \hat{R}$ is not geometrically reduced \[[Nagata](https://hdl.handle.net/2027/uc1.b5008742?urlappend=%3Bseq=225), App., (E3.3)\].